# adb shell command for real time data

Tags: android, shell, mobile, labview

I am working on a module in which my device under test will dial a call to a specific mobile number. I have connected that mobile to the local PC over USB(with Debugging mode ON). I need to monitor the status of the mobile in real time like Ringing, InCALL, Disconnected. Is there any adb shell command which tells the live status of the android phone?
I need to monitor this status in Labview application and based on the status if it is ringing I want to send command to accept the call.
Could anybody suggest the best method to automate this process?

Comment: have you checked `adb shell logcat` for any specific logs at ringing,incall,disconnected ? Definetely there will be some events or related prints

Answer (score 0):

Android send intent Broadcast to applications in your phone who are listening at phone status 
Add following user permission to receive phone state
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>`

Write a receiver service for receiving phone status

`<receiver android:name=".IncomingCall">   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Implement the reciever

`public class IncommingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
      Context context;

```
  @Override  
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){  
      try{  
       String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);  

          if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){  
               Toast.makeText(context, "Phone Is Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }  

          if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){  
               Toast.makeText(context, "Call Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }  

          if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){  
               Toast.makeText(context, "Phone Is Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }  
      }  
      catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
  }
```

}`

Then onReceive method of the above function call you can send command to receive.